# Right Angled Artin Group Reference request

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

The following should be true: every normal subgroup of a non-Abelian Right Angled Artin Group should contain a free group on two generators. Is there a standard reference one can cite for this?

Comment: $\mathbf{Z}\times\{1\}\subset\mathbf{Z}\times F_2$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the right question should be: what is the right statement :(

Comment: Probably the starting point should be Sageev and Wise, [The Tits alternative for CAT(0) cubical complexes][1]., Bull. London Math. Soc. 37 (2005), no. 5, 706–710

So the question is: when are there non-solvable normal subgroups?


  [1]: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2164832

Comment: @Lior: actually the question is when are there any SOLVABLE normal subgroups (I am saying never, except in trivial examples, such as direct products with abelian groups).

Comment: @Lior: an additional remark is that RAAGs are known to be linear (Davis-Januszkiewicz?), so the Tits alternative in that setting is due to J. Tits.

Comment: Yes, "non-" was supposed to be "no"

Comment: Igor, correct question, I think, is about center-less RAAGs. Proof should follow from Sageev-Wise with a bit of fiddling. 

Comment: You might be interested in Antolin--Minasyan's paper about the Tits alternative for graph products: http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2448 .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Igor, I assume the question is about centerless RAAGs. Then it follows from the classical result of A. Baudisch (see MR0634562): every 2-generated subgroup of a RAAG is abelian or $F_2$.

Indeed if $N$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup in a RAAG $G$, take any $x\in N$. Since $G$ is centerless  there exists $g\in G$ that does not commute with $x$. Then $\langle x,g\rangle\cong F_2$ and hence $\langle x, x^g \rangle \cong F_2$.

Comment: @Denis: thanks much! The argument you give actually seems to give more than I asked for: a normal subgroup is either central or contains an $F_2.$

Answer (score 8):

A right-angled Artin group $G$ is the fundamental group of the
compact non-positively curved cube complex called the 
Salvetti complex $X$. Thus $\tilde{X}$ is a CAT(0) space,
and the action of $G$ on $\tilde{X}$ is proper and cocompact.

Thus, by the [Solvable Subgroup Theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=3DjaqB08AwAC&lpg=PA249&ots=eNW6ZTW10t&dq=solvable%2520subgroup%2520theorem&pg=PA249#v=onepage&q&f=false),
every virtually solvable subgroup $H< G$ contains a finitely generated
abelian subgroup of finite index. Moreover, every element 
in $G$ will be semi-simple by Prop. 6.10 (2) from [Bridson-Haefliger](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.math.psu.edu%252Fpetrunin%252Fpapers%252Fscans%252Fbooks%252Fbridson.haefliger.pdf&ei=qgpuUPTpFYSQiQLTyoCgCw&usg=AFQjCNEhpIU1JkqEhAilaLlz3a5MaPeadg&sig2=nGpi7dPEG8zvTkgSbd9qLA).
By Corollary 7.2, there is an $H$-invariant closed convex
subspace of $\tilde{X}$ isometric to a product $Y\times \mathbb{E}^n$,
so that $H$ acts as the identity on $Y$ and acts cocompactly
on the $\mathbb{E}^n$ factor. Any isometry of $\tilde{X}$ 
which normalizes $H$ preserves $Y\times \mathbb{E}^n$ and its
splitting. We conclude that $\tilde{X}=Y\times\mathbb{E}^n$ when
$H$ is normal in $G$.

Now, I think for a CAT(0) cube complex $\tilde{X}$, the factorization
$Y\times \mathbb{E}^n$ should actually be a product of cube complexes.
This isn't quite right, since in the group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ there
are clearly $\mathbb{R}^k$ factors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are
not a factor of the cube complex structure. But I think if $H$ is
assumed to be a virtually solvable normal subgroup of $G$ 
and maximal with respect to this
property, then $\tilde{X}=Y\times \mathbb{E}^n$ should be a product
of cube complexes. I think it should be possible to prove this
 by analyzing links of vertices of the Salvetti complex, and
how the foliation by $\mathbb{E}^n$'s passes through them.

But this implies that $G=G_1\times \mathbb{Z}^n$ where $G_1$
is a right-angled Artin group, since each
edge of a cube of the Salvetti complex corresponds to a generator,
so a cube complex factor isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$ will give
generators commuting with every other generator.

As observed in one of the comments, $G$ satisfies the Tits alternative
since it is linear, so a normal subgroup is either virtually
solvable, and then $G$ splits off a $\mathbb{Z}^n$ factor, 
or the normal subgroup is not solvable and therefore must contain
a free subgroup. However, one would need to fill in the above missing
step to finish this argument.